# Why is 'There are most of us in the party' ungrammatical?

Tags: syntax

Sentence a: There are many of us in the party.
Sentence b: There are most of us in the party.

Why is sentence b ungrammatical? Is it a matter of some kind of constraints?

Comment: I suppose it is something about the 'There be' structure, but I can't tell which theory should I use to explain it...

Comment: I disagree with the close votes: though the question as stated is English-specific, it's about the linguistic explanation for a grammatical phenomenon rather than being an "is this correct usage" question, which I think is what that guideline is intended to exclude; also, the phenomenon in question is not restricted to English but is paralleled in many other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a constraint on existential sentences, in English and other languages, which says that the NP has to be indefinite:

> There is a cat on the bookcase.
> *There is the cat on the bookcase.

So the pattern you describe can be accounted for if we hypothesize that *most of us*, unlike *many of us*, is definite. (Obviously it doesn't contain a definite article, but that isn't a necessary condition of definiteness: e.g. phrases like *Mary, Mary's friend, this dog* are all definite but don't contain a definite article.)

To substantiate this it would be good to have independent evidence that *most of us* is definite, especially since semantically the question doesn't seem too clear. One of the most commonly used definiteness tests is this very "there is" construction, but using that would of course be circular; I can't think of another test which would apply in this case, but maybe others here can. Cross-linguistically, though, there are languages which clearly mark phrases like *most of N*, but not *many of N*, as definite, e.g.:

French:

> beaucoup de chiens "many dogs" (indef.)
> *la* plupart des chiens "most dogs" (def.)

Hebrew:

> harbe klavim "many dogs" (indef.)
> rov *ha*-klavim  "most dogs" (def.)

Comment: The first sentence should say _indefinite_ (or ‘must not be definite’), right?. As a more precise parallel to the many-vs-most test, you could use Scandinavian languages, where _flere/mere_ ‘more [count/non-count]’ is indefinite and _flest/mest_ ‘most [count/non-count]’ definite when used attributively: _Flere af hundene_ ‘more/several of the dogs’ vs _**de** flest**e** af hundene_ ‘most of the dogs’ (examples from Danish). This has the advantage of being transparently comparative/superlative, so the relationship is clearer.

Comment: _Most_ is superlative, and therefore definite by definition. I'm more concerned about the circularity of "existential sentences must not have definite NPs". If it's got a definite NP, it can't be existential, and vice versa. So are they equivalent categories, does one imply the other, or are they independent?

Comment: @jlawler Specifically with *most of* the semantics of superlatives seems less helpful because (unlike e.g. *the biggest cat*) it doesn't pick out a single unique entity or set. I don't understand your other point -- the ill-formedness of definites in existential constructions (*There is the cat on the bookcase) is a standard observation going back to Postal in 1970.

Comment: About English. It's a constraint on _there_-insertion.

Comment: @jlawler Going outside just English, superlatives are not necessarily definite by definition. I actually misspoke in my previous comment: the superlatives in Scandinavian are _not_ necessarily definite when used attributively, not even when used in the ‘most of’ construction. As in English, ‘most of’ _can_ appear in existential clauses, though not unrestrictedly so. “There are most of us at the party” is only grammatical when it means ‘the party is where the largest number of us are’ or ‘we are the most represented group at the party’.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for your answer! I reallly never knew that definiteness can be expressed without a determiner.....